# How to replace variable text in file by using Windows .cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have .ini file and there is a line with

```
HOST='pc-name'
```

fragment. But it can be something else instead of pc-name. HOST='random' or HOST='welcome' for example. I need to find it and replace with HOST='%COMPUTERNAME%' where %COMPUTERNAME% is real computer name where this .cmd file is running. I've only found how to replace static things, so the problem is to detect this fragment with random value. And = is interpreted as assignment operation but I need it as simple text symbol.

P.S. I need to do it with .cmd file.

Comment: You can use a regular expression search to find such strings.

Comment: What have you tried so far, what do you have trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

A tool to search/replace files/pipe lines/blocks: 1 command line

Use `msr.exe` in **my open project** https://github.com/qualiu/msr `tools` directory.

**For your case**: (Remove `-R` to preview replacing result;  Add `-K` to backup)

- Replace any content `HOST=.*` to `HOST=%COMPUTERNAME%` :

  `msr -p my.ini -t "^(HOST)=.*" -o "$1=\%COMPUTERNAME\%" -R`
- More general: ignore case, white-spaces:

  `msr -p my.ini -it "^(HOST)\s*=.*" -o "$1=\%COMPUTERNAME\%" -R`

#### Additionally:

- Use `msr-Win32.exe` if your windows is 32-bit.
- Recursively replace in multiple paths and files:

  `msr -rp directory1,dirN,file1,fileN -f "\.ini$" -it "^(HOST)\s*=.*" -o "$1=\%COMPUTERNAME\%" -R`

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like Notepad++ to open the .ini file.

You can then use a regular expression search to find such strings. For example, you can use `HOST='.*'` as a search expression with Search mode as "*Regular Expression*" in Notepad++. This will search for the pattern HOST='any value' and then you can replace it with `HOST='%COMPUTERNAME%'`

Using CMD, you can use
`findstr "HOST='.*'" < _place your .ini file name_ >.ini` to find all strings which match the pattern and then replace them

Comment: I need to do it with .cmd file.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/339118/regex-replace-from-command-line explains some tools you can use to achieve this.

Comment: I can use pure cmd only, this is a restriction.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that `HOME=` will always start in the first column and that the only thing after it could be a string enclosed in apostrophes, you could do something like.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%s IN (`TYPE "thefile.txt"`) DO (
    SET "STR=%%~s"

    IF "!STR:~0,6!" EQU "HOME='" (
        ECHO HOME='newsetting'
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO %%~s
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would have a file with one or more lines containing variables as

> HOST='%COMPUTERNAME%'

as you indicate halfway in your post, then you could easily have them replaced as follows. I'm assuming your file is called inputfile and your output goes to outputfile.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%I in (inputfile) do call echo %%I>> outputfile
```

Notes:

1. The above command should be inside a cmd script, otherwise one should use %I instead of %%I if one wants to run it from the cmd prompt directly.
2. The "call" statement makes sure that the variables are converted
   into their values. Without it, they would remain as variables.
3. Empty lines get discarded, not sure if there is a way to avoid that.
4. Make sure you don't put any spaces before the ">>" otherwise they will be there in your output file.